# jQuery mobile pop up adding &ui-state=dialog at the end of url

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I was using this sample code from jquery mobile demo page example.

```
<a href="#popupMenu" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slideup" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-gear ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a">Actions...</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu" data-theme="b">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:210px;">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Choose an action</li>
            <li><a href="#">View details</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

I i run this sample in jquery mobile site it works well but if i run it in my local system `&ui-state=dialog` is appended to the window url.